# Modificar "Puntos" archivo binario (modificar por SEEK )

Tags: java

Necesito ayuda con el siguiente trozo de código:

```js
 case 1:
System.out.println("Actualizar Puntos");
int registro = 1;
// Nuevos puntos (entrada del usuario)
punts = 40;
// Posición donde comienza el registro
int pos = 48 * (registro - 1);
// Mover a la posición donde empieza el dato
pos += 4 + 20 + 20;
raf.seek(pos);
raf.writeInt(punts);              

   break;
```

Al imprimir los datos por pantalla observo que actualiza todos los resultados a 40:

```
ID: 50
Nombre Instituto: inst1
Nombre Equipo: equi1
Puntos: 40

ID: 600
Nombre Instituto: inst2
Nombre Equipo: equip2
Puntos: 40

ID: 6000
Nombre Instituto: inst3
Nombre Equipo: equip3
Puntos: 40
```

Cada registro debería tener un número de puntos diferente. Por ejemplo: el primero 40 puntos, el segundo 60 puntos, el tercero 30 puntos, etc.

El problema es que todos los registros se actualizan a 40 cuando debería de ir registro por registro. No todos de golpe.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

***A petición de un usuario adjunto código completo para revisión:***

Parte 1  ( Donde se introducen los datos en el archivo binario )

```js
/**
 * OPCIO 1  ACTIVITAT 2
 */
package activitat2;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * ACTIVITAT 2 EAC 6
 * @author Montse
 */
    public class Opcio1{
    /**
     * En aquesta activitat la número 2 farem:
     * Introduir instituts
     * Listar instituts introduïts
     * Sortir
     * Tornar al menú principal
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     * @throws IOException
     */

    static void IntroduirInstituts() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        RandomAccessFile raf;
        raf = new RandomAccessFile("Partides.dat", "rw");

        System.out.println("HAS ESCOLLIT OPCIÓ 1");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Institutos que participarán en infoguardians");
        System.out.println("1-Registrar los datos de los institutos ");
        System.out.println("2-Listar todos los institutos");
        System.out.println("3-Volver al menú principal");
        System.out.println("4- Salir");
        System.out.println("Escoje una opción");

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

        int punts       = 0;
        int enterLlegit = 0;
        boolean llegit  = false;

        while(!llegit){
            llegit = lector.hasNextInt();
            if (llegit){

                enterLlegit = lector.nextInt();

                switch (enterLlegit){
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Registra los datos de los institutos:");
                    System.out.println("Quantos institutos participan en el concurso?");
                    boolean leido = false;
                    while(!leido){

                        leido = lector.hasNextInt();
                        if (leido){

                            int enterLlegit2 = lector.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("Numero total de centros: "+enterLlegit2);
                            System.out.println("El fitxer s'ha creat. Accés directe");
                            for (int j = 0, pos = 0; j < enterLlegit2; j++){
                                int i = 0;
                                i = enterLlegit2;
                                if(enterLlegit2 > 0){

                                    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                                    System.out.println("Introduce la info sobre el instituto:");
                                    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
                                    System.out.println("Id?");

                                    int idInst = lector.nextInt();

                                    System.out.println("Nom Institut:");

                                    String nomInst = lector.next();

                                    System.out.println("Nom Equip:");

                                    String nomEqui = lector.next();

                                    System.out.println();

                                    System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
                                    System.out.println("::INFORMACIÓN SOBRE CENTRO INSCRITO::");
                                    System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
                                    System.out.println("Id: " +idInst);
                                    System.out.println("Nom Institut: "+nomInst);
                                    System.out.println("Equip: "+nomEqui);
                                    System.out.println("Punts: "+punts);
                                    System.out.println();


                                    raf.seek(pos);
                                    raf.writeInt(idInst);
                                    pos +=4;
                                    raf.seek(pos);
                                    raf.writeUTF(nomInst);
                                    pos +=20;
                                    raf.seek(pos);
                                    raf.writeUTF(nomEqui);
                                    pos+=20;
                                    raf.seek(pos);
                                    raf.writeInt(punts);
                                    pos +=4;

                                }
                            }

                        }else {
                            System.out.println("No has escrito un entero, vuelve a intentarlo");
                            lector.next();
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("HAS ESCOGIDO LISTAR LOS INSTITUTOS");
                    System.out.println("------------------------------------");
                    for (int pos = 0;;){

                        try
                        {
                            raf.seek(pos);

                            System.out.println("ID: " +raf.readInt());
                            pos += 4;

                            raf.seek(pos);
                            System.out.println("Nombre Instituto: "+raf.readUTF());
                            pos += 20;

                            raf.seek(24);
                            System.out.println("Nombre Equipo: "+raf.readUTF());
                            pos += 20;

                            raf.seek(44);
                            System.out.println("Puntos: "+raf.readInt());
                            pos += 4;

                            System.out.println();
                        }
                        catch (EOFException e)
                        {
                            // Fin de archivo
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("TORNAR AL MENÚ PRINCIPAL::::");
                    MenuPrincipal.EscollirOpcio();

                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Hasta la próxima!");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("No has escrito una opción válida");
                    System.out.println("Fin del programa");
                    break;
                }

            }else {

                System.out.println("No has escrito un entero, vuelve a intentarlo");
                lector.next();
            }
        }
        lector.nextLine();


    }
}
```

Parte 2 del código donde quiero modificar:

```js
/**
 * OPCIO 2  ACTIVITAT 3
 */
package activitat2;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Montse
 */


 public class Opcio2 {
    /**
     * En aquesta clase farem les demandes de l'activitat 2
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     */
    static void ActualitzarInstituts() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        RandomAccessFile raf;
        raf = new RandomAccessFile("Partides.dat", "rw");

        System.out.println("HAS ESCOLLIT OPCIÓ 2");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Institutos que participarán en infoguardians");
        System.out.println("1-Actualizar Puntos");
        System.out.println("2- Salir");
        System.out.println("3- Volver al menú principal");
        System.out.println("Escoje una opción");

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

        int punts       = 0;
        int enterLlegit = 0;
        boolean llegit  = false;

        while(!llegit) {

            llegit = lector.hasNextInt();

            if (llegit) {

                enterLlegit = lector.nextInt();

                switch (enterLlegit) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Actualizar Puntos");
                    // Primero enseñaremos los intitutos que tenemos registrados
                    System.out.println("LOS CENTROS INTRODUCIDOS SÓN:::::::");
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------");

                    for (int pos = 0;;){

                        try
                        {
                            raf.seek(pos);

                            System.out.println("ID: " +raf.readInt());
                            pos += 4;

                            raf.seek(pos);
                            System.out.println("Nombre Instituto: "+raf.readUTF());
                            pos += 20;

                            raf.seek(24);
                            System.out.println("Nombre Equipo: "+raf.readUTF());
                            pos += 20;

                            raf.seek(44);
                            System.out.println("Puntos: "+raf.readInt());
                            pos += 4;

                            System.out.println();
                        }
                        catch (EOFException e)
                        {
                            // Fin de archivo

                        }
                        System.out.println("Actualizar Puntos");
                        int registro = 1;
                        // Nuevos puntos (entrada del usuario)
                        punts = 40;
                        // Posición donde comienza el registro
                        pos = 48 * (registro - 1);
                        // Mover a la posición donde empieza el dato
                        pos += 4 + 20 + 20;
                        raf.seek(pos);
                        raf.writeInt(punts);

                        break;
                    }

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Hasta la próxima!");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("No has escrito una opción válida");
                    System.out.println("Fin del programa");
                    break;
                }

            }else {
                System.out.println("No has escrito un entero, vuelve a intentarlo");
                lector.next();
            }
        }
        lector.nextLine();


    }
}
```

Comment: Hace falta que coloques más código para poder dar con el error. También cambiaría el título de la pregunta.

Comment: Edito! un segundo!

Comment: @user1598390 hecho! ;) si falta algo más avísame!

Comment: Una pregunta bien formulada comienza describiendo cual es el problema que tienes, luego dar a conocer parte de tu código para ayudar a resolver tu problema *específico*. Más info -> http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Tenés que usar un Scanner, como hacés cuando escogés la opción, cuando leés la ID, etc... Creo que deberías consultar al autor del código, ya que es obvio que no lo escribiste vos.

Comment: @Angus ya he probado con el scanner y no lo consigo.. he probado hacer:
 System.out.println("Punts?");
          punts = lector.nextInt();
          int registro = 1;
          pos =48* (registro -1);
          pos +=4+20+20;
          raf.seek(pos);
        raf.writeInt(punts);
        raf.seek(44);
        System.out.println("Puntos: "+raf.readInt());
        pos += 4;

Y me da error también.. si supiera hacerlo no pediría ayuda..

Comment: El problema es que me asigna lo x puntos a todas las posiciones de puntos y yo necesito hacerlo por separado.

Comment: @Hèctor gracias Hèctor ya he leido y la información y no sé como explicarlo mejor.. Lo siento. Siempre puedes hacer una revisión para explicarlo tú!

Comment: @MontseMkd No tengo como explicar tu problema si no lo puedo entender, creo que ese es el mismo problema que tienes tú... :(

Comment: @Hèctor 

Yo ya he puesto el código y la explicación así que haber si tenemos suerte y alguien nos ayuda!  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puesto que cada registro tiene una longitud de 48 bytes, del cual existen varios en el archivo, entonces para modificar los puntos en cada uno de ellos (cada uno con una puntuación diferente, desde luego), puede utilizarse un ciclo `for`.

```
for (int registro = 1;; registro++) {
    int pos = 48 * (registro - 1);
    try {
        System.out.printf("Registro #%02d%n", registro);
        pos += 4 + 20 + 20;

        // Lectura
        raf.seek(pos);
        System.out.printf("Puntos actuales: %d%n", raf.readInt());

        // Escritura
        System.out.print("Introducir puntos: ");
        int puntos = scanner.nextInt();
        raf.seek(pos);
        raf.writeInt(puntos);
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Cualquier operación de lectura (por ejemplo, `raf.readInt()`) después del final del archivo lanza la excepción `EOFException`, debido a que no se puede leer después de final del archivo (aunque sí escribir). Puede utilizarse esto para identificar el final de archivo y romper el ciclo `for`.

Answer (score 3):

```
 case 1:
System.out.println("Actualizar Puntos");
int registro = 1;
// Nuevos puntos (entrada del usuario)
punts = 40;
// Posición donde comienza el registro
int pos = 48 * (registro - 1);
// Mover a la posición donde empieza el dato
pos += 4 + 20 + 20;
raf.seek(pos);
raf.writeInt(punts);              

   break;
```

.

```
ID: 50
Nombre Instituto: inst1
Nombre Equipo: equi1
Puntos: 40

ID: 600
Nombre Instituto: inst2
Nombre Equipo: equip2
Puntos: 40

ID: 6000
Nombre Instituto: inst3
Nombre Equipo: equip3
Puntos: 40
```

no se si esto sera una verdadera respuesta a lo que usted busca, pero le comentare lo que veo segun entiendo lo que pregunta:

Usted dice

-> Al imprimir los datos por pantalla observo que actualiza todos los resultados a 40:

```
//..
// Nuevos puntos (entrada del usuario)
punts = 40;
//..
raf.writeInt(punts);
//..
```

yo en ningun lugar veo que usted asigne otro valor a la varible punts que no sea 40. Lo que se enlaza a lo que usted comenta despues

-> Cada registro debería tener un número de puntos diferente. Por ejemplo: el primero 40 puntos, el segundo 60 puntos, el tercero 30 puntos, etc.

No entiendo de donde saca que el primero 40, el segundo 60, tercero 30, ni por que tendria que almacenar esos valores, cuando punts = 40.

Esta parte tambien es algo confusa (para mi)

-> ...cuando debería de ir registro por registro.

```
//..
viendo esto -> int registro = 1;
y esto      -> int pos 48 * (registro -1);
```

lo que me imagino que usted quiere hacer es saltar desde una posicion a otra, la cual tiene la misma estructura interna para cambiar los bits/contenido de esa posicion.
Si es asi, por que registro siempre es igual a 1? no deberia de cambiar para ir avanzando en cada itereacion.

**UPDATE**

despues de añadir el codigo de @Paul Vargas, que funcionaba como se esperaba aparecio un error que no mostraba todos los registros al consultarlos pero si eran bien almacenados con el codigo de Paul, resulto ser que el error estaba aqui:

```
raf.seek(24); 
System.out.println("Nombre Equipo: "+raf.readUTF()); 
pos += 20; 

raf.seek(44); 
System.out.println("Puntos: "+raf.readInt()); 
pos += 4;
```

habia que cambiar raf.seek(pos);

Comment: Te contesto!

Los puntos es por poner un ejemplo, en mi ejercicio se le piden al usuario que actualice los puntos de todos los registros. En este caso me pongo a imaginar que he introducido 3 registros.

Por lo que necesito introducir 3 puntos diferentes ya que no tienen por que coincidir.

y si quiero saltar posición por posición pero solo para modificar la de puntos.

Comment: En este caso los registros son:
Instituto X
id
Nombre instituto
Nombre Equipo 
Puntos.

Solo necesito modificar la parte de puntos, el resto no ! ;)

Comment: @MontseMkd te comento la variable que se encarga de almacenar los puntos es punts, entonces esa variable es donde tienes que almacenar los nuevos puntos que quieres escribir, por ejemplo le piedes al usuario que los introduzcas y los almacenas ahi, o los pones de otra forma.

Comment: @MontseMkd Por otro lado por lo que puede ver los registros tienen un longitud de 48 y los ultimos 4 corresponde a donde almacenas los puntos (si no me equivoco) entonces si registro es igual a 1 escribira en el primero registro, si quieres escribir en el registro 3 tienes que cambiar el valor de registro, para que valga registro = 3

Comment: Si los últimos 4 corresponden a puntos. es decir el 48.

Pero la duda que tengo es que no se como:

- Leer cada registro. Es decir hago un 

punts = lector.nextInt() para que el usuario me diga cuando puntos ha conseguido el primer registro es decir el primer instituto.

Pero como hago para saber:
- Quantos intitutos hay registrados.
- Como actualizo los puntos de cada registro?

Comment: Entiendo lo que me dices pero no quiero poner cuantos Registros sino que el programa detecte cuantos hay.. :S

Comment: @MontseMkd esto de registro = 3 u otro numero te lo digo porque no se si puede darse el caso de que usted tenga un archivo con varios registros y si quiere modificar el registro que esta en el tercer lugar solo tiene que saltar los que estan antes y esto lo puede hacer al asignar rigistro = 3 o la posicion a la que desee saltar, sin tener que hacer ningun tipo de iteracion, seria algo asi como que selecionas el registro/intituto que digamos que es el tres pues creas una funcion que le pasas el lugar 3 e implementas un codigo similar al que usar pero ahora registro vale 3 y saltas a ese lugar

Comment: No te entiendo lo siento! :(

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33981/discussion-between-angel-angel-and-montse-mkd).

Comment: El archivo tendra 4 registros.

1 serà: instituto marítim, equipo X, Puntos 50
2 será: instituto tarra , equipo X, puntos 120
3 será: instituto obert, equipo X, puntos 130
4 será : instituto blabla equipo x, puntos 160.

Pero tengo que introducir los puntos por teclado. Es decir tiene que decirme cuantos puntos tiene el instituto X ? y yo actualizarlo